# Error al actualizar Api 30 a 31

Tags: android, mercadopago, mercadolibre

Quien me puede ayudar??? Hace varios días que no puedo generar mi APK para subir a la Playstore. Mi app estaba compilando con compileSdkVersion 30 y targetversion 30 actualice a (por politicas de playstore) a sdk y targetversion 31 y comienzan los problemas.
Para generar la apk debug y signed apk sin problemas, ahora cuando quiero subir a la playstore me dice

*"Has subido un APK o Android App Bundle que tiene una actividad, un alias de actividad, un servicio o un receptor de emisión con filtro de intents, pero sin establecer la propiedad android:exported. Este archivo no se puede instalar en Android 12 o versiones posteriores. Consulta developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported"*

Bien... veo el archivo `Androidmanifest.xml` --> Merged Manifest y los siguientes errores son de Mercado pago y razorpay.

> Merge Errors Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.features.checkout.CheckoutActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. Android_08-01-2022.app main manifest (this file), line 37 Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.razorpay.CheckoutActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. Android_08-01-2022.app main manifest (this file), line 17 Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.razorpay.RzpTokenReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. Android_08-01-2022.app main manifest (this file), line 11

A continuación Todo lo que hice para tratar de solucionar y sigue el problema.

- Invalidate caches
- crean project
- rebuild project
- Actualizar razorpay y mercado pago...
- implementation 'com.mercadopago.android.px:checkout:4.53.1' la actualice a implementation 'com.mercadopago.android.px:checkout:4.53.2'

```
     repositories {
         maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/hani-momanii/maven" }
     //    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
         maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
         maven { url 'https://artifacts.mercadolibre.com/repository/android-releases/'  }
```

Este error al tratar de construir la app signed para subir a playstore actulizando MercadoPago

```
Executing tasks: [:app:bundleRelease] in project C:\Users\milo\Desktop\APPAN BKP\1\Android 08-01-2022

Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 16 s 572 ms

> Configure project :app
WARNING: DSL element 'android.dataBinding.enabled' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'android.buildFeatures.dataBinding'.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
WARNING: DSL element 'android.dataBinding.enabled' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'android.buildFeatures.dataBinding'.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processReleaseGoogleServices UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingExportBuildInfoRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingExportFeaturePackageIdsRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:bundleReleaseResources
> Task :app:processReleaseResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\milo\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\8322820d8bc0952240c250b2101fdea0\\transformed\\material-1.3.0\\res\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":1979,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":137268,"endLine":1989,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":138036}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\milo\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\8322820d8bc0952240c250b2101fdea0\\transformed\\material-1.3.0\\res\\values\\values.xml:1980:5-1990:11: AAPT: error: expected enum but got (raw string) slide.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\milo\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\8322820d8bc0952240c250b2101fdea0\\transformed\\material-1.3.0\\res\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":2519,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":171462,"endLine":2525,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":171916}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\milo\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\8322820d8bc0952240c250b2101fdea0\\transformed\\material-1.3.0\\res\\values\\values.xml:2520:5-2526:11: AAPT: error: expected enum but got (raw string) fade.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

> Task :app:bundleReleaseResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\milo\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\8322820d8bc0952240c250b2101fdea0\\transformed\\material-1.3.0\\res\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":1979,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":137268,"endLine":1989,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":138036}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\milo\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\8322820d8bc0952240c250b2101fdea0\\transformed\\material-1.3.0\\res\\values\\values.xml:1980:5-1990:11: AAPT: error: expected enum but got (raw string) slide.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\milo\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\8322820d8bc0952240c250b2101fdea0\\transformed\\material-1.3.0\\res\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":2519,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":171462,"endLine":2525,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":171916}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\milo\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\8322820d8bc0952240c250b2101fdea0\\transformed\\material-1.3.0\\res\\values\\values.xml:2520:5-2526:11: AAPT: error: expected enum but got (raw string) fade.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

> Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED
> Task :app:desugarReleaseFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeExtDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:bundleReleaseResources FAILED
> Task :app:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:collectReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:configureReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:parseReleaseIntegrityConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\milo\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\8322820d8bc0952240c250b2101fdea0\transformed\material-1.3.0\res\values\values.xml:1980:5-1990:11: AAPT: error: expected enum but got (raw string) slide.
         
     C:\Users\milo\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\8322820d8bc0952240c250b2101fdea0\transformed\material-1.3.0\res\values\values.xml:2520:5-2526:11: AAPT: error: expected enum but got (raw string) fade.
         

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\milo\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\8322820d8bc0952240c250b2101fdea0\transformed\material-1.3.0\res\values\values.xml:1980:5-1990:11: AAPT: error: expected enum but got (raw string) slide.
         
     C:\Users\milo\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\8322820d8bc0952240c250b2101fdea0\transformed\material-1.3.0\res\values\values.xml:2520:5-2526:11: AAPT: error: expected enum but got (raw string) fade.
         

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 5m 36s
29 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 27 up-to-date
```

Alguna ayuda??

Comment: Agrega tu AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Me sale que es demasiado extenso si agrego en AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

El error:

> "Has subido un APK o Android App Bundle que tiene una actividad, un
> alias de actividad, un servicio o un receptor de emisión con filtro de
> intents, pero sin establecer la propiedad android:exported. Este
> archivo no se puede instalar en Android 12 o versiones posteriores.
> Consulta
> developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported"

en idioma inglés:

> Merge Errors Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified
> for element
> <activity#com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.features.checkout.CheckoutActivity>.
> Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an
> explicit value for android:exported when the corresponding component
> has an intent filter defined. See
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported
> for details.

Se refiere a que todos los elementos en tu AndroidManifest.xml que contengan `intent-filter` deben tener definida la propiedad [**android:exported="true"**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element?hl=es-419#exported)

> [**android:exported="true"**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element?hl=es-419#exported) Determina si los componentes de otras
> aplicaciones pueden iniciar la actividad: Si es "true", cualquier app
> puede acceder a la actividad y se puede iniciar con su nombre de clase
> exacto. Si es "false", la actividad solo se puede iniciar con
> componentes de la misma aplicación, aplicaciones con el mismo ID de
> usuario o componentes del sistema con privilegios. Este es el valor
> predeterminado cuando no hay filtros de intents.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A todos los elementos en tu AndroidManifest.xml ya sea activity, service, receiver, etc... que contengan "intent-filter" debes agregar `android:exported="true"`

---

Con respecto al segundo error:

> WARNING: DSL element 'android.dataBinding.enabled' is obsolete and has
> been replaced with 'android.buildFeatures.dataBinding'. It will be
> removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.

Debes habilitar la vinculación de datos, esto lo realizas dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle` en el bloque `android`, agrega el bloque `buildFeatures` conteniendo lo siguiente:

```
android {
    ...
    ...
    buildFeatures{ 
        dataBinding true 
        viewBinding true 
    }
}
```

Revisar:

**[Vinculación de datos Databinding](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/databinding?hl=es-419)**

Comment: Quiero poner  el Android Manifest. para ver si se paso algo de eso. Por que me salían  activity, service, receiver etc. y los solucione (creo) el error esta cuando actualizo Mercado pago o Razorpay

Comment: Ahora tienes otro error, he editado mi respuesta agregando como solucionar el otro detalle @Milo